# Dancing/Raging Mongoose and Time Stands Still synergy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

So, let us assume we have a level 20 swordsage with a  two hander, and with access to Time Stands Still and Raging Mongoose manoeuvres.

Using a swift action to initiate Raging Mongoose, and then initiating Time Stands Still, does one get:

- 2x(three attacks plus two from mongoose)
- 2x(three attacks) plus two from mongoose

From the wording I would assume it is the later, but still Ii would like to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, modifiers of any type do not compound on each other. For example, any two effects which double an attribute, when applied at the same time, triple it instead.

Therefore, I'd say that your second interpretation is correct. The two additional attacks are added after all other modifiers, and not multiplied at all. Likewise, the attack multiplier is applied only to your standard number of attacks, before any other modifiers.